# "after immigrating" Or "as immigrants"?

Tags: grammar, exam-questions

> ______, Tran, Maya, and their four children left much behind, including their family restaurant. (From ACT test)

Why I can't fill the blank with "after immigrating", but have to be "as immigrants"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying "After they *arrived* they left things behind." They didn't. They left things behind when they *departed* [from their country].

Saying "As immigrants" only solves the problem if you change the tense of the verb 'leave':

> "As immigrants they *had* left things behind."

It might be clearer to say:

> "When they **[emigrated](https://www.lexico.com/definition/emigrate)**, Tran, Maya, and their four children left much behind..."

[Btw, [immigrate](https://www.lexico.com/definition/immigrate) is an AmE word, not a BrE one. If you're not in the US that might be another problem.]

Comment: Indeed. As a fellow Brit, I'm perfectly happy with the noun form ***immigration*** (as a word, not as a global economic policy! :), but I don't really like the "verbified" versions of that one (*He emigrated* is much more natural to me than *I immigrated*). I've no idea why the orthography switches from single to double ***m*** depending on the initial vowel, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica: I agree. But how long till we too are immigrating? It's strange how seldom 'emigrate' and 'emigration' are heard these days. From a glance at Etymonline it seems we can blame the emi/immi schism on the Latins!

Comment: Re "It's strange how seldom 'emigrate' and 'emigration' are heard these days" - I'd say the verb ***[to] emigrate*** has always been reasonably common, but *not* the derived noun form ***emigration***. But it's the *opposite* with ***[to] immigrate*** (rare verb) and ***immigration*** (common noun). When I just checked [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+immigrate%2Cto+emigrate&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20immigrate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20emigrate%3B%2Cc0) I can see that's confirmed in spades for the ***verbs...***

Comment: ...but [for the corresponding derived nouns](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=immigration%2Cemigration&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimmigration%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cemigration%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cimmigration%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cemigration%3B%2Cc0), it seems that actually, ***emigration*** was the more common of the two until about 150 years ago (since when ***immigration*** has shot to prominence).

Comment: Interesting. You're right. it's 'emigration' and 'immigrate' that are less commonly heard at the moment. I still haven't heard 'immigrate'. How long before there's an equivalent of NGram based on *spoken* English?!

Comment: From what I've seen of current neural-net-based AI's transcribing recorded speech into text, YouTube could probably create an audio version of NGrams in a matter of weeks by feeding just a fraction of their footage through an AI designed to do that. As opposed to the current situation, where I assume if they analyse what they've got *at all*, it's only in order to figure out how to control our shopping habits more accurately!